# Live with Predictable Network Interface Name

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I'm facing for the first time with the new name scheme of network interfaces: Predictable Network Interface Name.

My question is NOT related if this scheme is better or worse... I'm just trying to understand how to use it correcly.

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Network_management) I read:

> When changing the interface naming scheme, do not forget to update all network-related configuration files and custom systemd unit files to reflect the change.

So I have to write in all the configuration files the actual interface name. In the previous scheme it was i.e. `eth0` and it just means the first ethernet card, with the known caveats if there are multiple interfaces.

Now, instead, I have to write the *predictable* name, that is composed of some easy parts (i.e. type of the interface) and other *un-predictable* ones like the MAC address. As far as I understand each card will have a different name.

I admit my question might appear fool, but I don't understand how to prepare a configuration file. Let's see an example, `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
profile static_eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

interface eth0
fallback static_eth0
```

What should I put instead of `eth0` in the o.s. image?
Only when I run the target machine I can retreive the actual name of the ethernet interface.

100% of my systems are headless, and I never connect a keyboard and display to them. Furthermore, if I have to send a spare part of the SBC do I need to reconfigure all?

Would you please help me to understand the correct usage?

ps. I know I can revert back to the old naming scheme... but that's not the point of my question.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/
it explains how the names are assigned

```
Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board devices (example: eno1)
Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers (example: ens1)
Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: enp2s0)
Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address (example: enx78e7d1ea46da)
Classic, unpredictable kernel-native ethX naming (example: eth0)

By default, systemd v197 will now name interfaces following policy 1) if that
information from the firmware is applicable and available, falling back to 2) if
that information from the firmware is applicable and available, falling back to 3)
if applicable, falling back to 5) in all other cases. Policy 4) is not used by 
default, but is available if the user chooses so.
```

So you could opt for a different approach, likely in your setup its easiest to take the mac, just reboot once an image that tries pxe/dhcp requests and note down the sended mac.

Another way, that may work, depending on your setup, would be interface groupings.

From "man interfaces"

```
   auto /eth*

   If the kernel knows about the interfaces with names lo, eth0 and eth1, then the above line is then interpreted as:

   auto eth0 eth1

   Note that there must still be valid "iface" stanzas for each matching interface.  However, it is possible to combine a pattern with a mapping to a logical interface, like so:

   auto /eth*=eth
   iface eth inet dhcp
```

So maybe if you only have one interface, but can't tell where it will be assigned, you could write  "auto /e*=eth" to catch all interfaces starting with e and address them inside the configuration file as "eth".